# Calculating molar conductance of CaCl2

Tags: homework, electrochemistry, conductivity

Ok, so the following question is given in my text book.

> Of the molar conductance value of $\ce{Ca^2+}$ and $\ce{Cl^-}$ at infinite dilution are respectively $118.88\times10^{-4}$ and $77.33\times10^{-4}$ then that of $\ce{CaCl2}$ is  (all have same unit)

So what I did was I added the molar conductivity of $\ce{Ca^2+}$ and added $2\times$ molar conductivity of  $\ce{Cl^-}$. I got the answer. It was one of the options. So I basically wanted to know: Did I do it correctly and is my process correct? And if I did it wrong then what is the correct process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the process is correct, but do you understand why?

Comment: As per my knowledge there is one mole of $Ca$ and 2 mole of $Cl$ in $CaCl_2$ that's why am i correct

Comment: @Akash I guess you were just lacking confidence about your answer when you had it solved all along.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating limiting molar conductivity

> limiting molar conductivity  =  V<sub>+</sub> A<sub>+</sub> +
> V<sub>-</sub> A<sub>-</sub>
>
> V<sub>+</sub>  =  number of cations per formula unit of the
> electrolyte
>
> V<sub>-</sub>  =  number of anions per formula unit of the
> electrolyte
>
> A<sub>+</sub> = molar conductivity of the cations
>
> A<sub>-</sub> = molar conductivity of the anions

So , your process is correct.